# Postgres Audit Trigger Individual Rows

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create a basic audit log trigger in postgres that I can use across various tables.

My only requirement is that the audit log show each updated value as a separate entry.
i.e. if an `INSERT` is performed into a table with 5 rows, I receive 5 entries in the audit log table (one for each value added) or if that row is deleted from the table, I receive 5 entries (one for each value removed)

I have looked at various examples and am still having trouble getting the output correct, especially when the operation is UPDATE.

Here is the basic trigger flow.

```
-- 1. Making the Audit Table

CREATE TABLE audit_table

-- The audit table which will show: 
-- Table, the ID of whats being changed, new columns, old columns, 
-- user, operation(insert update delete), and timestamp

(
"src_table" TEXT NOT NULL,
"src_id" INT NOT NULL,
"col_new"  TEXT,
"col_old" TEXT,
"user" TEXT DEFAULT current_user,
"action" TEXT NOT NULL,
"when_changed" TIMESTAMP
);

-- 2. Creating the base audit trigger function, the engine for processing changes --

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_trigger() 
 RETURNS trigger AS 
 
$$

BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' --Only shows new values
    THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_table ( "src_table", "src_id", "col_new", "user", "action", "when_changed")
                VALUES(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_RELID, row_to_json(NEW), current_user, TG_OP, current_timestamp);
        RETURN NEW;
        
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' --Shows new and old values
    THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_table ("src_table", "src_id", "col_new", "col_old", "user", "action", "when_changed")
                VALUES(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_RELID, row_to_json(NEW), row_to_json(OLD), current_user, TG_OP, current_timestamp);
        RETURN NEW;
        
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' --Only shows old values
    THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_table ("src_table", "src_id", "col_old", "user", "action", "when_changed")
                VALUES(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_RELID, row_to_json(OLD), current_user, TG_OP, current_timestamp);
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
END

$$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

-- 3. Basic logic for calling audit trigger on tables, works for any insert, update, delete

CREATE TRIGGER test_audit_trigger
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE 
 
 ON test_table
 
 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_trigger();
```

The issue:

- `row_to_json` returns the entire old or new payload as one column. I would like to return each change as a separate entry row in the audit_table, using for example `column_name` `old_value` `new_value` as a schema. What is the simplest way of achieving this? Having it be json is not a requirement.

Also not required:

- Having it be `BEFORE` keyword, if `AFTER` or a combination of the two is better.
- Having one trigger do all 3 functions, it can be a separate trigger or function per action
- Returning values that are not changed, for example if an `UPDATE` only changes 1 value, I do not need the unchanged values in the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution based on yours. One `AFTER` row trigger for `insert`, `update` and `delete`. The structure of `audit_table` is a bit different. Old and new values are saved as their text representation. You may wish to change the behaviour under `insert` and `delete` as they seem to be too verbose.

Unrelated but under your requirements the audit table has to implement the EAV (entity, attribute, value) antipattern.

```sql
drop table if exists audit_table;
create table audit_table
(
 src_table text not null,
 col_name text not null,
 v_old text,
 v_new text,
 "user" text not null default current_user,
 action text not null,
 when_changed timestamptz not null default current_timestamp
);

create or replace function audit_tf() returns trigger language plpgsql as 
$$
declare 
  k text;
  v text;
  j_new jsonb := to_jsonb(new);
  j_old jsonb := to_jsonb(old);
begin
    if TG_OP = 'INSERT' then -- only shows new values
        for k, v in select * from jsonb_each_text(j_new) loop
            insert into audit_table (src_table, col_name, v_new, action) 
            values (TG_TABLE_NAME, k, v, TG_OP);
        end loop;      
    elsif TG_OP = 'UPDATE' then -- shows new and old values 
        for k, v in select * from jsonb_each_text(j_new) loop
            if (v <> j_old ->> k) then
                insert into audit_table (src_table, col_name, v_new, v_old, action) 
                values (TG_TABLE_NAME, k, v, j_old ->> k, TG_OP);
            end if;
         end loop;  
    elsif TG_OP = 'DELETE' then -- only shows old values
        for k, v in select * from jsonb_each_text(j_old) loop
            insert into audit_table (src_table, col_name, v_old, action) 
            values (TG_TABLE_NAME, k, v, TG_OP);
        end loop;      
    end if;
    return null;
end;
$$;
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

-- Demo

drop table if exists delme;
create table delme (x integer, y integer, z text, t timestamptz default now());

create trigger test_audit_trigger
after insert or update or delete on delme
for each row execute procedure audit_tf();

insert into delme (x, y, z) values (2, 2, 'two');
update delme set x = 1, y = 10 where x = 2;
delete from delme where x = 1;
select src_table, col_name, v_old, v_new, action from audit_table;
```

| src_table | col_name | v_old | v_new | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| delme | t |  | 2021-12-28T00:21:03.966621 | INSERT |
| delme | x |  | 2 | INSERT |
| delme | y |  | 2 | INSERT |
| delme | z |  | two | INSERT |
| delme | x | 2 | 1 | UPDATE |
| delme | y | 2 | 10 | UPDATE |
| delme | t | 2021-12-28T00:21:03.966621 |  | DELETE |
| delme | x | 1 |  | DELETE |
| delme | y | 10 |  | DELETE |
| delme | z | two |  | DELETE |

Comment: This is wonderful, thanks so much @Stefanov-sm for your help! 

I will definitely look up the EAV antipattern and try to avoid it, new concept for me.